# Host address url not working for sharepoint site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have created web application on port 80 in sharepoint with host address like `http://subsite.site.com`.
I checked in IIS server host header was defined in the web site property. When I typed  `http://subsite.site.com` on IE browser on server itself showing undefined.

How to get `http://subsite.site.com` on server and from client machine (my local machine)?

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Is `subsite.site.com` registered in DNS?  You web browser or client resolves the network location portion of the URL (`subsite.site.com`) into an IP address using DNS before opening a TCP connection to the server.  If the DNS lookup fails, then it cannot create the HTTP/TCP connection.

Comment: You mean DNS on Main network server? or DNS entry in server where sharepoint web application installed?

Comment: The name `subsite` needs to be registered in the DNS server that is [*authoritative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Authoritative_name_server) for the DNS zone "site.com".  Read [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for a introduction to DNS.